# Point current location on google map api and fetch details about it

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Fetch user's current location's latitude and longitude and drop marker on it through google map api also display some information related to that location.

Comment: This web site is not for requesting code from other users, it is for asking other users about any issues you may be facing and requesting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google map provides a very good documentation about their API. As you want to use the marker on map you may consider using google's tutorial from their documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

For displaying information you may get the idea from here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows